# wants to return valid json object from controller

Tags: java, json, spring, model-view-controller

I tried a lot but didn't reach. I want to return valid Json object from the controller. I have put some data in the DB and want to list them. Here is my code

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"                                                    
 xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">  

 <servlet>  
 <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
 <init-param>  
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name><param-value>/WEB-INF/config/sdnext-servlet.xml</param-value></init-param>  
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
 <servlet-name>sdnext</servlet-name>  
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  

 <welcome-file-list>  
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
 </welcome-file-list>  

 </web-app>
```

**sdnext-servlet.xml**

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resources/database.properties"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dineshonjava"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        id="jspViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        id="sessionFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dineshonjava.model.Employee</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}  </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
        id="hibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and **EmployeeController.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<Employee> listAllUsers() {
    return employeeService.listEmployeess();
}

}
```

and it gives me this line in the console:

Hibernate:

```
select this_.EMPID as EMPID1_0_0_, this_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS2_0_0_, this_.EMPAGE as EMPAGE3_0_0_, 
 this_.EMPNAME as EMPNAME4_0_0_, this_.SALARY as SALARY5_0_0_ from employee this_
```

so how to get the values of the table and put it in Json object ?

Comment: what did you get actually as a response ?  please add your response you get

Comment: Do you have jackson-mapper-asl and jackson-core-asl jars in your classpath ?